# Format string to NSdate in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdate

My string is = "2015-08-26 14:21:40.557"

My code:

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:Z"

        var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(creationDateStr as String )
```

I get a nil date , what's the right format?

Comment: What time zone is that string? If you're getting this out of a database or from some web service, sometimes it's GMT/UTC/Zulu. You should confirm what time zone the time string is in.

Comment: Also, if this date format is for exchanging with some web service or the like, you should also set the `locale`. See Apple [Technical Q&A #1480](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1480/_index.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format must match your input string exactly, so

```
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
```

will do the job.

Note that `Z` is used for the timezone, not for (milli)seconds.

And `HH` is for 24 hours; `hh` only allows values between 01 and 12 and is usually paired with `a` to indicate AM/PM.

Answer (score 1):

```
        var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

        var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(creationDateStr as String )
```

Will return nil if your string is not in this date format. (ex. "5/26/2015" will return nil but "2015-05-26 12:30:00.123" will return a nsdate)

Answer (score 1):

The format is incorrect for the string you are attempting to parse.

The correct format is:

"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"

Parsing an incorrect format will return a nil value.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "2015-08-26 14:21:40.557"
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(str)
```

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you [include some explanation along with it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/159034) to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.